# Selenium ide not recording keys

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using the Selenium IDE in Chrome.  It records clicking and opening pages just fine, but doesn't record any typing.  It also doesn't send any typing either, the type and send keys commands show as being completed but don't actually type any keys in the browser.
The command looks like this:

send keys | //*[@class='ace_content'] | bob

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Selenium IDE is the new version, and it lacks a lot of features from the old version. To record the typing, have you tried to lose the focus of the field first? In the old one it only recorded those values when the field lose focus. Also, "sendKeys" don't work in the old version as well, i use the "type" command.